# if/else statement for wordpress metabox

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, meta-boxes

I have this code on some pages to display an image that is uploaded via custom metabox on a wordpress page. However, I'm trying to figure out how to wrap it in an if/else statement, so that if a user does not upload an image, then the code is not displayed.

Here's my code on the page template:

```
<div id="image-slider" class="rs-full">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <img src="<?php global $post; $image = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wpb_rs_full', true ); echo $image; ?>" alt="<?php echo get_the_title($ID); ?>">
                    </div> <!-- /.row-fluid -->
    </div><!-- /.container -->
</div><!-- /#image-slider -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
global $post; 
$image = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wpb_rs_full', true );

if($image){ ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="<?php echo get_the_title($ID); ?>">
<?php } ?>
```

That should be the condition you are looking for.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!! Was trying to go at it way too complicated. I figured it was easier than I was making it - and it is. Thanks again!